# jQuery.val() only returns value on second event with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working with a (legacy) project using jQuery UI's datepicker. I need to validate that the date entered in the element is a minimum of 24 hours from the current date. I'm grabbing the value of the datepicker element on blur to validate it. The issue is that attempting to get the value of the input that has the datepicker applied is behaving inconsistently. .val() only returns a value on the second blur event, and then it returns the value of the blur event preceding that one. Driving me nuts.

Markup:

```
<form action="" method="GET" novalidate="novalidate" class="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Entry Date/Time</legend>

        <label for="ad" class="screen-reader-text">Entry Date</label>
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        <input type="text" id="entry-date" name="ad" placeholder="March 4, 2019" autocomplete="off">
    </fieldset>

    <div class="submit-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" class="parking-submit" value="Submit">
    </div><!--ends submit-wrapper-->
</form>
```

JS:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.form input[type=text]').datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        nextText: '>>',
        prevText: '<<',
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy'
    });

  $('#entry-date').blur(function(){
       var now = new Date();
       console.log(now);
       var tomorrow = new Date(now.getTime() + 86400000); //1 day in ms
       console.log(tomorrow);
       var dateGiven = $('#entry-date').val();
       console.log('Set value is' + dateGiven);
  });
});
```

Here's [a pen](https://codepen.io/david-brown/pen/JzRMJO) showing the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is because placeholder is not value. By the way `Date.now()`, without being a `new` instance, will give you the milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

Comment: instead of `$('#entry-date').val()` use this context like `$(this).val()`

Comment: `@guradio`, wouln't that be the same thing, within a jQuery Event listener?

Comment: this is the current target although they are the same it will differ. if it wasnt the ID since ID is unique

Comment: It will not differ on an Event attached directly to the Element by id. So that won't do anything. The problem is that placeholder is not value.

Comment: Why don't you simply disable all the dates that are 24h+ from now-date?

Comment: Also, why don't you use the datepicker's `onSelect: function(dateText) {` method ?

Comment: Great idea to set the minDate to +1, which I should have done, but that still doesn't validate to exactly 24 hours unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blur, use change.

```
   $('#entry-date').change(function(){
       var now = new Date();
       console.log(now);
       var tomorrow = new Date(now.getTime() + 86400000); //1 day in ms
       console.log(tomorrow);
       var dateGiven = $('#entry-date').val();
       console.log('Set value is' + dateGiven);
  });
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The problem is that the blur event happens before the value has been updated. 

This is evident from the previous value being logged, and no value being logged the first time.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, either. Definitely works.